# Will my code cause memory leakage?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-leaks

I have this for loop that iterates through a vector.
Then it checks if the given name equals the name of the model.

Finally it creates a pointer and returns it. Now my question is if there is going to be any memory leak if i don't delete the pointer?

```
Model3D* ModelMemory::GetModel(char* name)
{
   for (std::vector<Model3D*>::reverse_iterator it = mModels->rbegin();it != mModel->rend();it++)
    {
        Model3D *model = *it;
        if (model->GetName() == name)
        {
             return model;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

--EDIT--

So my goal here is to store all my 3d models (stored in Model3D classes) in a vector,
so that i can retrieve it later using the name of the Model3D.
Is there maybe a better way to do this? Because it seems like my way is not really good programming...

Comment: I guess it will be simply incorrect - why are you comparing pointers?

Comment: If GetName() returns an object that implements == for char* (say std::string), it can be correct.

Comment: I'm storing all the models in a vector, and when i want to retrieve them, it's easier to remember them by name.
Could there be a better way?

Comment: Use some kind of map, like std::unordered_map<std::string, Model3D*>. It will provide you a direct way to access you model through their name.

Comment: @MatthieuRouget `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shard_ptr<Model3D>>` would be a better alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, they were really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not dynamically allocating any memory. This is static allocation

```
Model3D *model = *it;
```

and it will be destroyed when the context block of this variable ends (i.e. when you return from this method). It's only statically allocated pointer.

Dynamically allocation is done with the `new` operator and there isn't any.

Simple rule to check for leaks is to have `delete` for every `new`.

You can check your memory leaks with `valgrind` terminal tool.

Comment: It's assigning a _pointer value_ to a variable that has _automatic storage duration_. This is different from _static storage duration_ which is what **static allocation** _could_ be interpreted as.

Comment: The pointer will **not** be deleted when the context block ends. It will be **destroyed**, just like any other variable; but the destructor for a pointer does nothing.

Comment: I didn't meant deletion as deletion of the pointer's referenced object. Destroy sounds better, thank you, edited.

Answer (score 3):

No, there wont be memory leakage, of course if you delete all models later. Also, use strcmp() to compare two strings

Comment: Or take the name as reference to a constant `std::string`

Comment: @WouterStandaert As long as it's not deleted you'll be ok. I suggest you switch to using smart pointers to avoid the possibility of accessing the object after it's been deleted otherwise you risk undefined behavior.